# Erro - Acender Led com 74HC595

Tags: arduino

Olá

Eu estou tentando acender o **led 1** que esta no **pino 1** do **74HC595** e o resto ficar apagado e depois apagar o **led 1** e acender **somente** o **led 2** que esta no **pino 2** do **74HC595**, mas o problema que eu estou tendo é que todos os leds ficam acesos juntos, oque pode estar errado ?

```
#define latchPin 5
#define clockPin 6
#define dataPin 4

void setup() {

pinMode(latchPin, OUTPUT);
pinMode(clockPin, OUTPUT);
pinMode(dataPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {

digitalWrite(latchPin, HIGH);
shiftOut(dataPin, clockPin, LSBFIRST, 0b10000000);
digitalWrite(latchPin, LOW);
delay(1000);
digitalWrite(latchPin, HIGH);
shiftOut(dataPin, clockPin, LSBFIRST, 0b01000000);
digitalWrite(latchPin, LOW);
delay(1000);

}
```

Obrigado

Comment: Isso depende muito de como o 74HC595 está ligado no Arduino. Por ser um conversor serial/paralelo, fica difícil responder sem o diagrama. Perguntas sobre hardware não são no escopo do site, mas no caso talvez o diagrama sirva para analisarmos a parte do software.

Comment: Uma tentativa seria usar um `digitalWrite(clockPin, LOW)` antes do `shiftOut`, caso o clock do 74hC595 funcione na subida do sinal.

Comment: Outra coisa, dependendo de como você ligou o 74HC595, a sequência correta seria `latchPin -> LOW`, `shiftOut` e depois `latchPin -> HIGH`, o que seria o inverso do seu código. De qq forma, sem o diagrama, fica complicado afirmar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente usar um delay entre os high no loop é melhor

```
#define latchPin 5
#define clockPin 6
#define dataPin 4
#define tempoAtualiza 1
void setup() {

pinMode(latchPin, OUTPUT);
pinMode(clockPin, OUTPUT);
pinMode(dataPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {

digitalWrite(latchPin, HIGH);
delay(tempoAtualiza * 1000);
digitalWrite(latchPin, LOW);
delay(tempoAtualiza * 1000);

digitalWrite(latchPin, HIGH);
delay(tempoAtualiza * 1000);
digitalWrite(latchPin, LOW);
delay(tempoAtualiza * 1000);

}
```